# Get all drives for a user, including drives from sites, without admin consent

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm implementing OneDrive as a cloud provider in an application using the authorization code flow, so I can get access token in behalf of a user, I'm using the [Graph API SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet), one of the requirements that I have it should be able to get the list of the Drives for Document Libraries that the user has access using the Graph API, but I don't know how to do it without admin consent and considering that the user that is logged in can have only read-only access or maybe owner, but probably not administration rights.

I've read a lot of possible solutions, but all of them consider that I have access to the Site ID, or Group ID, and to use any of these solutions I need to ask for admin consent permissions, so the question is, can I get all the list of a drive for a user, drives that the user already has access, without admin consent and without knowing beforehand the Sites IDs or the Group IDs?

When I login with this user account in OneDrive, I can see the Drives from Document Libraries for every Site that the user has access without Admin Consent, I need to do the same with the API.

Comment: so from top two paragraph i see you want a general user (with very little permissions) to be able list all user's OneDrive via API. From last part you asking a user to list his own Libraries via API. Could you clearfy which one is your question? or both are.

Comment: I added more details, the last paragraph is just an example of what I'm trying to achieve, when you login using the OneDrive application, you can see the Drives of the Sites without admin consent, I need to do the same but using the Graph API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I assume you want to list the Document Libraries.

If we use a administrator to login, We can use the following steps to get the drives from sites.

Step1, we can use the API: `/sites/root` to get all the sites in the root.

we can get the id for the every site in the root.

Step2, we can use this API: `/sites/{siteId}/drives` to get the drive in one site. The `siteId` parameter is the result in step1.

However, the user doesn't have access to the root site of the tenant. So it looks like that it is an legit response. Without accessing to root site, the user won't be able to query any information for that root site.

Comment: To my understanding, this endpoint just returns the list of Drive Items for the root folder of the personal drive of the user, not for the site's drives.

Comment: Do you want get all the site?

Comment: Yes, the drives from all the sites that the user has access. For example, you have a user for OneDrive Business and you were invited to a Site called "Company Site", when you login to OneDrive you can see the files in your Personal Drive, but also you have access to the files on the Drive of the site "Company Site". I'd like to do the same using the API.

With this endpoint: GET /me/drive/root/children

You just have access to the items in your personal drive.

Comment: You can use this API: `/me/drives` to get all the drives, it will list all the drives of you. Then you can loop traversal all the drives

Comment: I've tried this endpoint, is just returning the personal drive of the user, not the drives from the sites, even if the user has site's drives.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to use that endpoint, the problem is, how can I use that endpoint without knowing the Sites Ids beforehand. I need a way to discover the sites ids, and it looks like there is not an easy to do it without admin consent and using other endpoints.

Comment: You can use `/sites/root` to get the tenant root site. And then traversing the results

Comment: Thanks for the help @kikang, I've just tried that endpoint and I'm receiving an access denied error, even if I have the scope Sites.ReadWrite.All, the details of the error are here

"error": {
        "code": "accessDenied",
        "message": "The caller does not have permission to perform the action.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "15ba41fb-bc24-4d70-b6da-2a938c602fb5",
            "date": "2018-09-17T23:51:54"
        }
    }

Comment: Did you have grant the 'Sites.Read.All' permission?

Comment: You can use the explorer to test these scenarios, https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer


But you need to have a business account to be able to login and test it.

Comment: I have tried this endpoint in Graph Explore with my business account. And it worked from my end.

Comment: Mmm that's interesting, are you administrator of the account or something?, or are you a regular user?, in my case is not working with the API explorer.

Comment: Here are more details about that, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44930705/https-graph-microsoft-com-v1-0-sites-root-is-not-working-for-tenant, basically you need a specific permission for that, but I don't have it, so I can not use that endpoint :(.

Comment: I'm so sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway, it looks like there's no easy way for now to discover the sites for a regular user, without admin consent or specific permissions.

Comment: I have edit my answer, could you please provide more info for the answer and mark it answer to help more people?